# How can I roll back to the very beginning a big open source project like Calibre?

Tags: git, github, version-control, open-source, git-commit

I use this software "Callibre" for ebook conversion and management, it is the best out there and open-source. I want to learn the inner workings of it and **reverse engineer** it.

Since it is on github, it must have an entire history of commits, who did what and when.

[Callibre](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre) has been in production for 7 years now, there must be a long history of commits, my only concern is how to roll it back to the very beginning and step through every major commit that added functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open github or any other program (i use GitBash to see the branch of a project) to acces the projects history and just go down to the fist entry (might take you a while if  you say its a 7 year project) and then open the first pushed file. From there you just follow the branches and you can see what has been changed by the developpers if i am not mistaken.